# How to import data from Bugzilla version 3.0 to latest 4.2. I am using MySQL database

Tags: bugzilla

I have installed new version on Linux Centos. I am older version installed on anther machine. Now want to import all old data to the latest version. Kindly leave suggestion if you have gone through this process.

Answer (score 1):

This is all well documented in the Bugzilla wiki. See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Move_Installation

Answer (score 0):

Once your database is reloaded where you want you just need to [process like explain here](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/installation.html#install-bzfiles) and BugZilla will check your database and upgrade it all alone . The tool works perfectly for having tested successfully an upgrade from bgz 2.2.21 to 3.5 ;)